# How to pass a single value in api which contains forward slash in python api request using http

Tags: python-3.x, http, request

```
#python3.10
from lib.http_requests import HttpRequests

base_url = "http://localhost"
http = HttpRequests(base_url)
auth_header = {a':'token','b':'id'}
http.session.headers.update(auth_header)

var = "abc/test/123"
url: f"http://localhost/api/v1/{var}"
response = http.get(url, verify=Fale)==200
print (f"response.code)`
```

In above function var is a single value, but when I pass it in above request it gives 404 error as request does not consider it a single value due to forward slash "/" in it.

I tried to replace "/"  in var with %2F  but still getting 404 error.
Query: how to handle a API endpoint value which has forward slash in name as to access it via http request.

Comment: I verified the above api in postman and I found that in curl command also the var part is passed with %2F  in pllace of / . e,g, (abc%2Ftest%2F123) and able to fetch the value